# Why does my dojo DateTextBox display with components on separate lines?

Tags: javascript, html, css, dojo, dijit.form

I'm using dojo `1.13.0` on my site and most things work, but when I try to add a `DateTextBox` to my form, I get this:

One line with "Date Event Starts",

one line with down-pointing triangle,

one line with X,

and one line with a blank input box , like below screen :

[image]

The page has following in the header:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="print" />
<script>dojoConfig = {async: true, parseOnLoad: false}</script>
<script src="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/dojo/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    require(["dojo/parser", "dojox/form/Manager", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser) {
        parser.parse();
    });
</script>
```

In the body:

```
<body class="claro myCssClass">
...
<div>
  <label for="eed-date-starts">Date Event Starts</label>&nbsp;
  <input id="eed-date-starts" name="eed-date-starts" data-dojo-observer="" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
</div>
...
</body>
```

I don't see any errors in the developer tools console (other than mixed content because I'm pulling fonts from 'http://themes.googleusercontent.com/...', and I'm on an https site).

It looks like the elements all have their dojo structure. I get a **div** with class dijitComboBox that contains a **div** with class dijitDownArrowButton that contains an **input** with class dijitInputField. I get what looks like proper sources. I get a dojo folder that contains a dijit folder that contains a themes/claro folder with a claro.css file in it.

If I click on the down-pointing arrow, the contents for the month widget appear at the bottom of the page, unformatted. So, it appears the actions are working, just not the formatting.

Does anyone have any advice how to debug this problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're putting the [`claro.css`](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css) theme in `media="print"`
and due to this the widget isn't rendered correctly , because the theme is used only for print devices (when start printing ) and not for screen device (see this [article](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_link_media.asp)) :

change the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo TEMPLATE_DIR; ?>/dojo/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" media="print" />` media attribute to `screen` (or remove it ) and it'll work correctly :

See below Snippet for both cases :

**No media attr  ( all device ) :**

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dojox/form/Manager", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser) {
  parser.parse();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet"  />
<body class="claro">
  <div>
  <label for="eed-date-starts">Date Event Starts</label>&nbsp;
  <input id="eed-date-starts" name="eed-date-starts" data-dojo-observer="" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
</div>
</body>
```

**With media =  print :**

```js
require(["dojo/parser", "dojox/form/Manager", "dijit/form/DateTextBox", "dojo/domReady!"], function(parser) {
  parser.parse();
});
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.4/dojo/dojo.js"></script>
<link href="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.10.0/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print" />
<body class="claro">
  <div>
  <label for="eed-date-starts">Date Event Starts</label>&nbsp;
  <input id="eed-date-starts" name="eed-date-starts" data-dojo-observer="" type="text" data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks, Boo. That was the problem. Good catch!